# Flask-sqlalchemy filter by unix interval

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I store the `created_at` column as a unix integer on my `Post` table. I need to filter all posts that have a `created_at` unix timestamp that is between `23h59` and `24h00` old, from the start of that specific day.

In other words, I need to filter all of the posts that are in their last minute of that that 24h interval since they have been created.

This query works for posts that are less than a day old

```
post_min = now - 86400
post_max = now - 86400 + 60

posts = Post.query.filter(Post.created_at >= post_min, Post.created_at < post_max).all()
```

How do I do this for posts that are older than a day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use modulo arithmetic:

```
(now % (60 * 60 * 24)) >= (60 * 60 * 24 - 60)
```

This spells out the multiplication.  You can of course write this as:

```
(now % 86400) >= (86400 - 60)
```

It might not be obvious to most people (or even you in the future) that `60*60*24` = `86400`.

Comment: Oh yes, that's exactly it. My final query was `Post.query.filter((now - Post.created_at) % 86400 >= post_min, (now - Post.created_at) % 86400 < post_max).all()` where `post_min = 86400 - 60` and `post_max = 86400`